# How do I fix this PHP code?

Tags: php, xml

I have to create a live search on a website. I have to use PHP, but I have never studied it and I am pretty much a beginner in programming.

I have an XML-file as a database and the aim is to get node values and display them as suggestions as a user types in something. The problem with this code is that it spits out all of the node values onto the web page.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("collection.xml");
$books = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("book");

$q = $_GET["q"];

if (strlen($q) > 0) {
$hint = "";

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $name = $book->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo "$name <br/>";
}

}

if ($hint == "")
{
$response="no suggestion";
}
else
{
$response=$hint;
}
//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Here is the XML-file:

```
<books>

  <book>
    <name>Harry Potter</name>
    <quantity> 50 </quantity>
    <price>19.90</price>
  </book>


  <book>
    <name>Casino Royale</name>
    <quantity> 50 </quantity>
    <price>12.99</price>
  </book>


  <book>
    <name>The Great Gatsby</name>
    <quantity> 40 </quantity>
    <price>14.90</price>
  </book>

</books>
```

Can someone please help me fix this issue so that I can continue working on my project. Thank you in advance for your time and help! Aprreciate it a lot!

Comment: Compare `$name` to `$q`? A real database would be much easier..

Comment: Add a relevant snippet of your XML file to your post.

Comment: Please mention xml file code also in question

Comment: *"The problem with this code is that it spits out all of the node values onto the web page."* - That's the part I don't get here; you're going to have to elaborate on it and post a sample xml file with the results you're looking to get. Or, do you mean that what shows up is "code"?

Comment: @Fred -ii- what I meant to say was that it shows all of the "name" nodes from the xml-file directly onto the web page and these should be displayed as suggestions only when a user types in something.

Comment: ok well someone posted an answer below, see that. If that doesn't solve it, then you'll need to post the method you mention here: *"when a user types in something"* - if that's coming from a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
$hint = "";

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $name = $book->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo "$name <br/>";
}
```

Notice that you have a "foreach loop" here.  The "$name=$book...." line simply reads the value of that particular XML node and assigns it to the $name variable.  Then you are doing a call to echo $name.  So in essence, all you're doing here is reading the value of the XML node and printing it.  No part of your code compares the $name to your search query ($q).  It seems that what you *want* to happen is only print out books that somehow match $q.

In order to do that we need to apply some logic to your foreach loop to only print out values that match $q.

Here is a suggestion:

```
$hint = "";

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $name = $book->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // Let's only show this book if $q appears somewhere in $name.
    if (strpos($name, $q) !== false && strpos($name, $q) >= 0) 
    { 
       echo $name . "<br />"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Unfotunately it still doesn't work :(